# how to get the default style of uinavigationbar for a uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make an uiview look just like the default uinavigationbar in ios 8.

I don't want to hardcode the values so would like to take the uinavigationbar color, height , width and the border at the bottom and apply the same to a custom uiview.

Is there any way I can achieve it ?

```
  self.headerBar.backgroundColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor;
```

I tried the above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K I finally had to combine the following

[UIColor colorWithRed:(247/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(247/255.0) alpha:1];

for the uiview colour than had to put in another uiview that i added as a subview to the original view with small height so that it looks like a border and gave it colour dark gray and alpha 0.4f. One thing to note here is that the border can also be created using layer but that by default doens't take care of orientation changes.

As for height width just gave the height width as per the superviews bounds to which this custom navigation bar is to be attached.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `UIToolBar` and set its properties accordingly as in `UINavigationBar`, like `tintColor`, `barTintColor`, `translucent`, etc..

Note: `UIToolBar` inherits from `UIView`

---

If you are using `UIView` and want to get the navigation bar color then its the `barTintColor` property you should use and not the `backgroundColor`

self.headerBar.backgroundColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor;

Comment: uitoolbar than again needs to customized for my purpose as I need to have  uimages and customizations... so instead i just have a uiview on the top and the default navigationbar is hidden